# zsh+ohmyzsh+powerlevel9k: completions stop working when issuing 'sudo -s'

Tags: shell, zsh, sudo, oh-my-zsh, macos-highsierra

I am having strange issue with zsh and ohmyzsh(with powerlevel9k theme) on MacOS High Sierra.

After installing ohmyzsh when issuing `sudo -s` getting annoying and strange output of some script. And all completions stop working. Absolutely the same configuration on Linux works just as expected.

Here is how it looks like:

```
user@host% sudo -s

bracketed-paste-magic () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
colors () {
    emulate -L zsh
    typeset -Ag color colour
    color=(00 none 01 bold 02 faint 22 normal 03 standout 23 no-standout 04 underline 24 no-underline 05 blink 25 no-blink 07 reverse 27 no-reverse 08 conceal 28 no-conceal 30 black 40 bg-black 31 red 41 bg-red 32 green 42 bg-green 33 yellow 43 bg-yellow 34 blue 44 bg-blue 35 magenta 45 bg-magenta 36 cyan 46 bg-cyan 37 white 47 bg-white 39 default 49 bg-default)
    local k
    for k in ${(k)color}
    do
        color[${color[$k]}]=$k
    done
    for k in ${color[(I)3?]}
    do
        color[fg-${color[$k]}]=$k
    done
    color[grey]=${color[black]}
    color[fg-grey]=${color[grey]}
    color[bg-grey]=${color[bg-black]}
    colour=(${(kv)color})
    local lc=$'\e[' rc=m
    typeset -Hg reset_color bold_color
    reset_color="$lc${color[none]}$rc"
    bold_color="$lc${color[bold]}$rc"
    typeset -AHg fg fg_bold fg_no_bold
    for k in ${(k)color[(I)fg-*]}
    do
        fg[${k#fg-}]="$lc${color[$k]}$rc"
        fg_bold[${k#fg-}]="$lc${color[bold]};${color[$k]}$rc"
        fg_no_bold[${k#fg-}]="$lc${color[normal]};${color[$k]}$rc"
    done
    typeset -AHg bg bg_bold bg_no_bold
    for k in ${(k)color[(I)bg-*]}
    do
        bg[${k#bg-}]="$lc${color[$k]}$rc"
        bg_bold[${k#bg-}]="$lc${color[bold]};${color[$k]}$rc"
        bg_no_bold[${k#bg-}]="$lc${color[normal]};${color[$k]}$rc"
    done
}
compdump () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
compinit () {
    emulate -L zsh
    setopt extendedglob
    typeset _i_dumpfile _i_files _i_line _i_done _i_dir _i_autodump=1
    typeset _i_tag _i_file _i_addfiles _i_fail=ask _i_check=yes _i_name
    while [[ $# -gt 0 && $1 = -[dDiuC] ]]
    do
        case "$1" in
            (-d) _i_autodump=1
                shift
                if [[ $# -gt 0 && "$1" != -[dfQC] ]]
                then
                    _i_dumpfile="$1"
                    shift
                fi ;;
            (-D) _i_autodump=0
                shift ;;
            (-i) _i_fail=ign
                shift ;;
            (-u) _i_fail=use
                shift ;;
            (-C) _i_check=
                shift ;;
        esac
    done
    typeset -gHA _comps _services _patcomps _postpatcomps
    typeset -gHA _compautos
    typeset -gHA _lastcomp
    if [[ -n $_i_dumpfile ]]
    then
        typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="$_i_dumpfile"
    else
        typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompdump"
    fi
    typeset -gHa _comp_options
    _comp_options=(bareglobqual extendedglob glob multibyte multifuncdef nullglob rcexpandparam unset NO_allexport NO_aliases NO_cshnullglob NO_cshjunkiequotes NO_errexit NO_errreturn NO_globassign NO_globsubst NO_histsubstpattern NO_ignorebraces NO_ignoreclosebraces NO_kshglob NO_ksharrays NO_kshtypeset NO_markdirs NO_octalzeroes NO_posixbuiltins NO_posixidentifiers NO_shwordsplit NO_shglob NO_warnnestedvar NO_warncreateglobal)
    typeset -gH _comp_setup='local -A _comp_caller_options;
             _comp_caller_options=(${(kv)options[@]});
             setopt localoptions localtraps localpatterns ${_comp_options[@]};
             local IFS=$'\'\ \\t\\r\\n\\0\'';
             builtin enable -p \| \~ \( \? \* \[ \< \^ \# 2>&-;
             exec </dev/null;
             trap - ZERR;
             local -a reply;
             local REPLY;
             local REPORTTIME;
             unset REPORTTIME'
    typeset -ga compprefuncs comppostfuncs
    compprefuncs=()
    comppostfuncs=()
    : $funcstack
    compdef () {
        local opt autol type func delete eval new i ret=0 cmd svc
        local -a match mbegin mend
        emulate -L zsh
        setopt extendedglob
        if (( ! $# ))
        then
            print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
            return 1
        fi
        while getopts "anpPkKde" opt
        do
            case "$opt" in
                (a) autol=yes  ;;
                (n) new=yes  ;;
                ([pPkK]) if [[ -n "$type" ]]
                    then
                        print -u2 "$0: type already set to $type"
                        return 1
                    fi
                    if [[ "$opt" = p ]]
                    then
                        type=pattern
                    elif [[ "$opt" = P ]]
                    then
                        type=postpattern
                    elif [[ "$opt" = K ]]
                    then
                        type=widgetkey
                    else
                        type=key
                    fi ;;
                (d) delete=yes  ;;
                (e) eval=yes  ;;
            esac
        done
        shift OPTIND-1
        if (( ! $# ))
        then
            print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
            return 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "$delete" ]]
        then
            if [[ -z "$eval" ]] && [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
            then
                while (( $# ))
                do
                    if [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                    then
                        cmd="${1%%\=*}"
                        svc="${1#*\=}"
                        func="$_comps[${_services[(r)$svc]:-$svc}]"
                        [[ -n ${_services[$svc]} ]] && svc=${_services[$svc]}
                        [[ -z "$func" ]] && func="${${_patcomps[(K)$svc][1]}:-${_postpatcomps[(K)$svc][1]}}"
                        if [[ -n "$func" ]]
                        then
                            _comps[$cmd]="$func"
                            _services[$cmd]="$svc"
                        else
                            print -u2 "$0: unknown command or service: $svc"
                            ret=1
                        fi
                    else
                        print -u2 "$0: invalid argument: $1"
                        ret=1
                    fi
                    shift
                done
                return ret
            fi
            func="$1"
            [[ -n "$autol" ]] && autoload -Uz "$func"
            shift
            case "$type" in
                (widgetkey) while [[ -n $1 ]]
                    do
                        if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]
                        then
                            print -u2 "$0: compdef -K requires <widget> <comp-widget> <key>"
                            return 1
                        fi
                        [[ $1 = _* ]] || 1="_$1"
                        [[ $2 = .* ]] || 2=".$2"
                        [[ $2 = .menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                        zle -C "$1" "$2" "$func"
                        if [[ -n $new ]]
                        then
                            bindkey "$3" | IFS=$' \t' read -A opt
                            [[ $opt[-1] = undefined-key ]] && bindkey "$3" "$1"
                        else
                            bindkey "$3" "$1"
                        fi
                        shift 3
                    done ;;
                (key) if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]
                    then
                        print -u2 "$0: missing keys"
                        return 1
                    fi
                    if [[ $1 = .* ]]
                    then
                        [[ $1 = .menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                        zle -C "$func" "$1" "$func"
                    else
                        [[ $1 = menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                        zle -C "$func" ".$1" "$func"
                    fi
                    shift
                    for i
                    do
                        if [[ -n $new ]]
                        then
                            bindkey "$i" | IFS=$' \t' read -A opt
                            [[ $opt[-1] = undefined-key ]] || continue
                        fi
                        bindkey "$i" "$func"
                    done ;;
                (*) while (( $# ))
                    do
                        if [[ "$1" = -N ]]
                        then
                            type=normal
                        elif [[ "$1" = -p ]]
                        then
                            type=pattern
                        elif [[ "$1" = -P ]]
                        then
                            type=postpattern
                        else
                            case "$type" in
                                (pattern) if [[ $1 = (#b)(*)=(*) ]]
                                    then
                                        _patcomps[$match[1]]="=$match[2]=$func"
                                    else
                                        _patcomps[$1]="$func"
                                    fi ;;
                                (postpattern) if [[ $1 = (#b)(*)=(*) ]]
                                    then
                                        _postpatcomps[$match[1]]="=$match[2]=$func"
                                    else
                                        _postpatcomps[$1]="$func"
                                    fi ;;
                                (*) if [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                                    then
                                        cmd="${1%%\=*}"
                                        svc=yes
                                    else
                                        cmd="$1"
                                        svc=
                                    fi
                                    if [[ -z "$new" || -z "${_comps[$1]}" ]]
                                    then
                                        _comps[$cmd]="$func"
                                        [[ -n "$svc" ]] && _services[$cmd]="${1#*\=}"
                                    fi ;;
                            esac
                        fi
                        shift
                    done ;;
            esac
        else
            case "$type" in
                (pattern) unset "_patcomps[$^@]" ;;
                (postpattern) unset "_postpatcomps[$^@]" ;;
                (key) print -u2 "$0: cannot restore key bindings"
                    return 1 ;;
                (*) unset "_comps[$^@]" ;;
            esac
        fi
    }
    typeset _i_wdirs _i_wfiles
    _i_wdirs=()
    _i_wfiles=()
    autoload -Uz compaudit
    if [[ -n "$_i_check" ]]
    then
        typeset _i_q
        if ! eval compaudit
        then
            if [[ -n "$_i_q" ]]
            then
                if [[ "$_i_fail" = ask ]]
                then
                    if ! read -q "?zsh compinit: insecure $_i_q, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure $_i_q and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? "
                    then
                        print -u2 "$0: initialization aborted"
                        unfunction compinit compdef
                        unset _comp_dumpfile _comp_secure compprefuncs comppostfuncs _comps _patcomps _postpatcomps _compautos _lastcomp
                        return 1
                    fi
                    _i_wfiles=()
                    _i_wdirs=()
                else
                    (( $#_i_wfiles )) && _i_files=("${(@)_i_files:#(${(j:|:)_i_wfiles%.zwc})}")
                    (( $#_i_wdirs )) && _i_files=("${(@)_i_files:#(${(j:|:)_i_wdirs%.zwc})/*}")
                fi
            fi
            typeset -g _comp_secure=yes
        fi
    fi
    autoload -Uz compdump compinstall
    _i_done=''
    if [[ -f "$_comp_dumpfile" ]]
    then
        if [[ -n "$_i_check" ]]
        then
            IFS=$' \t' read -rA _i_line < "$_comp_dumpfile"
            if [[ _i_autodump -eq 1 && $_i_line[2] -eq $#_i_files && $ZSH_VERSION = $_i_line[4] ]]
            then
                builtin . "$_comp_dumpfile"
                _i_done=yes
            fi
        else
            builtin . "$_comp_dumpfile"
            _i_done=yes
        fi
    fi
    if [[ -z "$_i_done" ]]
    then
        typeset -A _i_test
        for _i_dir in $fpath
        do
            [[ $_i_dir = . ]] && continue
            (( $_i_wdirs[(I)$_i_dir] )) && continue
            for _i_file in $_i_dir/^([^_]*|*~|*.zwc)(N)
            do
                _i_name="${_i_file:t}"
                (( $+_i_test[$_i_name] + $_i_wfiles[(I)$_i_file] )) && continue
                _i_test[$_i_name]=yes
                IFS=$' \t' read -rA _i_line < $_i_file
                _i_tag=$_i_line[1]
                shift _i_line
                case $_i_tag in
                    (\#compdef) if [[ $_i_line[1] = -[pPkK](n|) ]]
                        then
                            compdef ${_i_line[1]}na "${_i_name}" "${(@)_i_line[2,-1]}"
                        else
                            compdef -na "${_i_name}" "${_i_line[@]}"
                        fi ;;
                    (\#autoload) autoload -Uz "$_i_line[@]" ${_i_name}
                        [[ "$_i_line" != \ # ]] && _compautos[${_i_name}]="$_i_line"  ;;
                esac
            done
        done
        if [[ $_i_autodump = 1 ]]
        then
            compdump
        fi
    fi
    for _i_line in complete-word delete-char-or-list expand-or-complete expand-or-complete-prefix list-choices menu-complete menu-expand-or-complete reverse-menu-complete
    do
        zle -C $_i_line .$_i_line _main_complete
    done
    zle -la menu-select && zle -C menu-select .menu-select _main_complete
    bindkey '^i' | IFS=$' \t' read -A _i_line
    if [[ ${_i_line[2]} = expand-or-complete ]] && zstyle -a ':completion:' completer _i_line && (( ${_i_line[(i)_expand]} <= ${#_i_line} ))
    then
        bindkey '^i' complete-word
    fi
    unfunction compinit compaudit
    autoload -Uz compinit compaudit
    return 0
}
compinstall () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
down-line-or-beginning-search () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XU
}
edit-command-line () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XU
}
is-at-least () {
    emulate -L zsh
    local IFS=".-" min_cnt=0 ver_cnt=0 part min_ver version order
    min_ver=(${=1})
    version=(${=2:-$ZSH_VERSION} 0)
    while (( $min_cnt <= ${#min_ver} ))
    do
        while [[ "$part" != <-> ]]
        do
            (( ++ver_cnt > ${#version} )) && return 0
            if [[ ${version[ver_cnt]} = *[0-9][^0-9]* ]]
            then
                order=(${version[ver_cnt]} ${min_ver[ver_cnt]})
                if [[ ${version[ver_cnt]} = <->* ]]
                then
                    [[ $order != ${${(On)order}} ]] && return 1
                else
                    [[ $order != ${${(O)order}} ]] && return 1
                fi
                [[ $order[1] != $order[2] ]] && return 0
            fi
            part=${version[ver_cnt]##*[^0-9]}
        done
        while true
        do
            (( ++min_cnt > ${#min_ver} )) && return 0
            [[ ${min_ver[min_cnt]} = <-> ]] && break
        done
        (( part > min_ver[min_cnt] )) && return 0
        (( part < min_ver[min_cnt] )) && return 1
        part=''
    done
}
up-line-or-beginning-search () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XU
}
url-quote-magic () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}

root@host# echo $SHELL
zsh

root@host#
```

Any ideas why could it happen? I know that `sudo -s` overwrites all environment variables, but don't think it may be an issue.

Env vars:

```
root@host# echo $SHELL
zhs

root@host# dscl . -read $HOME UserShell
UserShell: /bin/zsh
```

Same for regular user.

Comment: `sudo -s` starts a new shell as the user *root*. This also means that the shell will take its configuration from *root*. As you get "annoying and strange output of some script", I would guess that *root's* `zsh` configuration is broken. It might also be `bash`, if your current user's login shell is not `zsh`. Could you please edit your question to contain the output in question, as well as the outputs of  `echo $SHELL` and `dscl . -read $HOME UserShell`?

Comment: the contents of output is already in the question, please read carefully. I have added the outputs of two other commands for regular user and root

Comment: Sorry about that. I overlooked the initial shell prompt and assumed it to be your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue seems to be that *root* has a different zsh configuration than your user. as `sudo -s` uses the configuration of the target user (*root*) instead of the calling user, you get a different zsh configuration.

The output looks like it could come from the `functions` built-in (or `typeset -f` or `declare -f`, which are equivalent), which seems to be called in one of *root's* configuration scripts:

```
/root/.zshrc
/root/.zshenv
/root/.zprofile
/root/.zlogin
```

If all, you want to do is to give *root* the same zsh configuration your regular user has, you can just copy it:

1. log in as *root*, e.g. `sudo -s`
2. move away any zsh configuration files *root* might have

   ```
   mkdir ~/zsh-old-conf
   mv ~/.zshrc ~/.zshenv ~/.zprofile ~/.zlogin ~/.oh-my-zsh ~/zsh-old-conf
   ```
3. copy your regular users configuration into *root's* home:

   ```
   cp -r /Users/REGULAR/.zshrc /Users/REGULAR/.oh-my-zsh ~/
   ```
4. Check, if the configuration now works. To be on the save side, leave the current session open and log in as root from a different terminal. That way you can revert the changes, if the configuration should not work for some reason.

Comment: I thought so before I have created this issue... The problem is that this is an automated ansible setup.. the configuration is absolutely identical for root user and non-root user. Therefore the chances that this solution could help were very low... I tried it now and it did not help.

Comment: In fact, when doing `sudo -s` the `$HOME` variable still shows the home dir of non-root user, therefore I can even remove all `.zsh*` and `oh-my-zhs`-related files from `/var/root/` and still see zsh+ohmyzsh working, when starting completely new shell and doing `sudo -s` there... But the output still persists..

Comment: That is … strange. I confess, that I did not test this on a Mac, but it seems that `sudo -s` works differently on Mac than on Linux as for me `$HOME` is reset to `/root`. Can you try `sudo -i`? It is similar to `-s` but tries to simulate an initial login, reseting environment variables to user defaults, reading configuration, etc..

Comment: I can tell you more.. When I did all this, the root user on my mac was disabled.. it's a macos silly feature, so it's not possible to login to the system as root, but if you are a non-root user with admin priviledges, then you are allowed to do `sudo -s` although plain `su` will not work and will return a simple `Sorry` string

Comment: So technically speaking, in this case the root user still uses the non-root user's zsh/oh-my-zsh configuration... So I thought maybe it's just because of that... But even after enabling "traditional" sudo user it's still the same...

Comment: Strange thing that with `sudo -i` my `$SHELL` is `/bin/sh` although I manually have changed it to `root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/usr/local/bin/zsh` in my `/etc/passwd`

Comment: It is entirely possible that MacOS does not (no longer?) care, what you set in `/etc/passwd`. Note that the regular users are not even listed there. If I understand the manpage correctly (and if it actually describes what really happens) it might be, that you get a `/bin/sh` session instead of `zsh` when you run `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`. You could try `sudo -i zsh -l`. The only other thing I can think of is to *not* run shell sessions as root and intead just run `sudo COMMAND` whenever you need elevated permissions. It seems to me that Apple really does not want users to log in as root.

Comment: that is interesting, but when I did `sudo -i zsh -l` it worked as expected... why????

Comment: Without a command `sudo -i` decides on its own, which shell to start. And on MacOS this seems to be `/bin/sh`.  By explicitly passing `zsh -l` as argument, you force `sudo` to run `zsh`. `-l` tells `zsh` to run as *login shell*, so it reads all of the above mentioned configuration files. It may also be possible to leave it out or replace it with `-i` (for *interactive shell*), then it would only read from `.zshrc` and `.zshenv`.

Comment: Ok, when I do `sudo -i` - I indeed get /bin/sh. When do `sudo -i zsh` - then I get /usr/local/bin/zsh with that weird output which is in OP. And only when I tell sudo to use zsh as *login shell*: `sudo -i zsh -l`, I get the normal expected behaviour. Do you have any ideas how to explain this?

Comment: Oh wait!!! I tried it a couple more times and now I get this output even with `sudo -i zsh -l`... That's just crazy! I am so confused.

Comment: Found other people with the same issue and without solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182414/oh-my-zsh-completion-not-working